# factorial of a number

Tags: javascript

I have the following code but it is not giving perfect result for factorial can u find it out plz

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
 <head>
  <title> New Document </title>
  <script type="text/javascript">
 function fact(num)
 {
    var x=parseInt(num);
    //alert(x+1);
    if(x>0)
        x=x* fact(x-1);
    alert(x);
 }
  </script>
 </head>

 <body>
 <form name="f1">
  Enter the Number  :<input type="text" length="8" name="txt1"><br>
  <input type="button" value="Find factiorial" onclick="fact(txt1.value)">
  </form>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=javascript+factorial

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/mohittadhiyal/6w64x0sL/10/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Fast factorial function in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3959211/fast-factorial-function-in-javascript)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You have to `return` the value. Here you go:

```
function fact(x) {
   if(x==0) {
      return 1;
   }
   return x * fact(x-1);
}

function run(number) {
    alert(fact(parseInt(number, 10)));
}
```

and

```
<input type="button" value="Find factiorial" onclick="run(txt1.value)">
```

*(How to make it work for negative numbers I leave up to you ;) (but I showed in this post anyway))*

Just for fun, a more correct, non recursive algorithm:

```
function fact(x) {
       if(x == 0) {
           return 1;
       }
       if(x < 0 ) {
           return undefined;
       }
       for(var i = x; --i; ) {
           x *= i;
       }
       return x;
}
```

Comment: The recursive algorithm doesn't have a base case. The non-recursive function is wrong as well.

Comment: @dheerosaur: Yep, for the recursive algorithm, fixed that (still early for me ;)). But why is the non-recursive one wrong? It works for me (see here http://jsfiddle.net/fgpPJ/1/) @Mihir: It works now.

Comment: i found one thing.. when i place if(x>0){ return x* fact(x-1)} the result is NaN.. where as when i place if(x==0){return 1} return x*fact(x-1).. it is showing correct result. what is the difference between those two blocks of code

Comment: Sorry, the non-recursive one is right. I was looking for the idiomatic check in `for`.

Comment: @Mihir - in the second snippet, all code paths *return a number*. On the first, you need `return 1` after the `if` - it isn't a complete function without it.

Comment: @Mihir: In the first, if `x` is equal to zero, the function will return nothing (`undefined`) because it only returns something if `x>0`. But number multiplied with `undefined` gives `undefined` (or `NaN` not sure).

Answer (score 5):

Use loop its easy to implement

```
function fact(num)
{
    if(num<0)
     return "Undefined";
    var fact=1;
    for(var i=num;i>1;i--)
      fact*=i;
    return fact;
 }

<input type="button" value="Find factiorial" onclick="alert(fact(6))">
```

Answer (score 5):

```
function factorial(n) {
  return (n != 1) ? n * factorial(n - 1) : 1;
}

alert( factorial(5) );
```

You can try to use recursion method

Answer (score 3):

1. Your function doesn't return anything, ever.
2. What do you do when x is 0?
3. Minor point - apart from `alert`, you don't really do anything with the returned value.

Try this instead, if you will (hover over the text):

> `if(x==0) return 1;`
>         `return x * fact(x-1);`

Working example: http://jsbin.com/apuka3/2

Comment: How do you create the hover effect?

Comment: @Tomas: Start the line with `>!` -  http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1191/add-markdown-support-for-hidden-until-you-click-text-aka-spoilers

Answer (score 2):

You need to have a `return` in your function in the first place. ;)

Answer (score 2):

```js
//This is fastest way to implement factorial
const fact = n => !n ? 1 : n * fact(--n);

console.log(fact(10))
```

Answer (score 1):

I wrote this and it works.

```js
  var d = 1;
  for (num; num > 1; num--) {
    d *= num;
  }
  return d;
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a short recursive version:

```js
function doFact(n) {
  return +!(+(n)) || doFact(n - 1) * n;
}

function factorialFromInput() {
  var theInputVal = document.getElementsByTagName("input")[0].value;
  var theContainer = document.getElementById("resultContainer");
  theContainer.innerHTML = "" + doFact(Math.abs(theInputVal));
}
```

```css
.wrapper>* {
  line-height: 2em;
  width: 30%;
}
#resultContainer {
  border: outset grey;
  min-height: 1.1em;
  padding-left: 0.3em;
  background-color: #eff0f1;
  overflow: scroll;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <input type="text" id="valEntered">
  <br>
  <button onclick="factorialFromInput();">Calculate Factorial</button>
  <br>
  <div id="resultContainer"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Recursion in JS is open to stack overflow error and also very slow. Looping by other means is better. My contribution to factorial code would be a straightforward one;

```js
var fact = n => n > 0 ? Array.from({length: n}, (_,i) => i+1)
                             .reduce((p,c) => p*c)
                      : 1;
console.log(fact(5));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function fact(n) {
  if (n > 1) {
    return n * fact(n-1);
  } else {
    return 1;
  }
}
console.log(fact(5));
```

Using **ternary operator** we replace the above code in a single line of code as below

```
function fact(n) {
      return (n != 1) ? n * fact(n - 1) : 1;
 }
console.log(fact(5));
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the very easiest way and latest JS(ES6)

```
factorial = n =>  n - 1 > 0 ? n * factorial(n - 1) : n;

//output
console.log(factorial(5));
```

Here I used ES6 arrow function. For better understanding please see what is [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions).

Answer (score 0):

The important part of the function is this line:

```
 x = x * fact(x-1);
```

but the `fact` function does not return a value, so this is the same as `x * undefined`. Try adding `return x;` to the bottom of your function.

Answer (score 0):

1) When X=0 function should return 1;
2) Added return;

```
 function fact(num)
 {
    var x=parseInt(num);
    //alert(x+1);
    if(x>0)
        x=x* fact(x-1);
    else
        x=1;
    return x;
 }
```

usage

```
<input type="button" value="Find factiorial" onclick="alert(run(fact.value));">
```

Answer (score 0):

A slight edit to Anton's code:

```
function fact(x) {
   if(x>0)
       return x* fact(x-1);
   if(x===0)
       return 1;
   return null;

}
```

(factorial of a negative doesn't exist, but factorial of 0 is equal to 1, in this case, if a number is smaller than 0, the function will return null)

Comment: @JavedAkram Please [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/359494/535122) to understand what `===` means.

Answer (score 0):

What about:

```
function fact(n) {
  n = Math.round(n);
  if (n < 2) {
    return 1;
  }
  else {
    return n * fact(n - 1);
  }
}
```

?

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion:

```
function fact(x) {
    if (x<0) {
        return Infinity
    };
    var _= 1
    for ($=1;$<=x;++$) {
        _*=$
    };
    return _
};
```

It simply returns the factorial of whatever "x" is.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one I made using a while loop:

```
function factorialize(num) 
{
  i = 1;
  b = 1;
  while (i < num) {
    b = b + (b * i);
    i = i + 1;
    }
return b;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 <script src="jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>
<script>
    $(function () {
        var target = 5;
        var factorial = 1;
        for (var i = 1; i <= target; i++) {
            factorial *= i;
        }
        alert(factorial);
       });
</script>
```

you can set any value in target and this logic will calculate Factorial.
[image: click to see output screen]

Thanks... :)

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why no one used dynamic programming to answer this, it's by far the most efficient way to build something on a factorial in my view.

```
 var mem = [];

 function fact(num)
 {
    var x = parseInt(num);

    if (x == 0 || x == 1) return 1;

    mem[x] = x * fact(x-1);

    return mem[x];
 }
```

Comment: mem[x] is not re-accessed for a given 'num'. So this is not DP, just simple memoize/caching.

Answer (score 0):

a very simple form:

```
function fact() {
    var x = document.getElementById("txtf").value;
    var f=1;
    for (var i=1; i <= x ; i++){
        f = f*i;
    }
    document.getElementById('showR').innerHTML= f;
}


 <input type="text" id="txtf" value="3">
   <input type="button" id="btnf" value="click for calculate" onclick="fact()">
   <p id="showR">/Factoriel/</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    function factorial(num) {

    var result = 1;

    for (var i = 1; i <= num; i++) {
        result = result * i;

    }

    return result;
}
//call function e.g factorial(4).. 1*2*3*4 it will evaluate in ascending order
```

Comment: Your answer would be better with some explanations. Click on the edit link at bottom left of it.

Answer (score 0):

```
var factorialNumber , factorial=1;
factorialNumber=prompt("Factorial Number" , "write Factorial Number");
for(var i = 1; i<= factorialNumber;i++){
    factorial *= i;
}
alert(factorial);
```

The code above first defines two variables, `factorialNumber` and `factorial`. `factorial` is initialized with 1. `factorialNumber` will get the result of the `prompt` (a number is expected) and then, using a cycle, in each step, factorial is multiplied with the index of the step, which is represented by `i`. When successfully calculated, we show the result using `alert`.

Comment: Please add an explanation to your code. Code only answers are generally frowned upon

Comment: How is my code? is it good? Did bi help? I checked it was not bad  What's your idea? By the way i am 17 years old

Comment: It is fine, however, it is nothing different than some of the other answers here. My remark was mainly that people like to get an explanation of what the code does, next to a working example

Answer (score 0):

## With a Do loop, it is pretty easy.

```
    <table>
    <tr>
        <th>Amount of integers</th>
        <th>Answer</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th><input id="int" type="number"/></th>
        <th><input id="answer" type="number"/></th>
    </tr>
</table>
<button onclick="calculate()">calculate</button>
<script>
    function calculate() {
        var input = document.getElementById("int").value;
        var int = 1;

        do {
            var product = int *= input;
            input--;
        } while (input > 0);
        answer.value = product;
    }
</script>
```

You first set a table to act as a way to input your variable and have a place to output the answer. You also add a button to execute your function.

The input variable is the value entered by the user. You also have int variable as a placeholder.

Inside the do loop you then another variable that is the product, it takes your placeholder variable and times it by the input. After this the input decrements, as long as input value is then greater than zero the loop keeps iterating.

Then at the end, it posts the answer to the 'answer' id tag in the table.

Answer (score 0):

```
function factorial(num){
    if(num<1||typeof num!=='number'){
    return undefined
  }
  if(num===1){
    return num
  }
    return num*factorial(num-1)
}
console.log(factorial(3))
```

https://jsfiddle.net/mohittadhiyal/6w64x0sL/10/

Answer (score 0):

```
function factorial (n) {
  if (n > 1) {
    return n * factorial(n-1);
  }
  return 1;
}
console.log("recursive way => ",factorial(5));
```

Answer (score 0):

I've seen a recursive approach used in many places (Eloquent JavaScript etc). Here, the function is called recursively until it reaches 0, which should not be the case. We should only call the function till it is >= 2 because the last number we need to multiply by is 1.

It's a very minor change, and probably does not matter. Curious to know what other people think of it. Assuming it is a valid positive integer.

```js
/**
 * Popular approach - the recursive function is called till x is 0
 * 
 * @param x
 */
function popularFactorial(x) {
    console.log(x)
    if(x === 0) {
        return 1
    } else {
        return x * popularFactorial(x - 1)
    }
}
var result = popularFactorial(8)
console.log(result)

/**
 * Using this approach, the recursive function is called one less time
 * i.e till x is 1
 * 
 * @param x 
 */
function factorial(x) {
    console.log(x)
    if(x === 0) {
      return 1
    } else if(x >= 2) {
        return x * factorial(x - 1)
    }
    return x
}
var result = factorial(8)
console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function factorial(n) {
    return [...Array(n + 1).keys()].slice(1).reduce((total, currentValue) => total * currentValue, 1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i am quite new to javascript and would be happy to know any improvements that could be made to this answer

```js
var a = 1;
function factorial(num) {
    if (num == 0) {
        return 1;
    } else if (num < 0) {
        return undefined;
    } else {
    for(i = num; i > 0; i--){
        a *= i;
    }
    return a;
    }
}
var b = factorial(5);
console.log(b);
```

Comment: Hi there. Welcome to stackoverflow. This should be a question instead of an answer. The answer section is just for answers. But you can create a new question and link to this post as a reference.