# Array Factorial. Getting NaN Output. Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, nested-loops, nan, factorial

```
var array = [5,4,3,2,1];

document.write("<br>Facorial: " + factorial(array));

//factorial function Ex. 5! = 5*4*3*2*1 = 120

function factorial(params){
        var f = 1;
        for (i = 0; i <= params.length; ++i){
            for (j = 1; j <= params[i]; j++){
                f = f * params[j];
            }
        }
        return f;
    }
```

I'm trying to make a program where the user inputs a bunch of random numbers in an array and the program calculates different things about those numbers.

I'm trying to have each individual number within my array be factorialed and then presented in the same form.

How I have it right now I'm getting NaN for my output.

What am I doing wrong? Or am I maybe not doing enough?

CURRENT OUTPUT

```
Factorial: NaN
```

WHAT I WANT

```
Factorial: 120,24,6,2,1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrong (or at least: odd) things in your code:

- `f` is a number. You seem to expect your function to return an array, though?
- `i <= params.length` should be `i < params.length`. Array indices start at 0, and end at `length-1`.
- You are multiplying your accumulator variable with `params[j]` - where `j` is any number smaller than the currently looked-at array item. This is the reason why you get `NaN` - when `i == 0`, it loops until `j == 5`, and `params[5]` is `undefined` - resulting in a `NaN` result.

What you want seems to be

```
function factorial(n) {
    // function that computes the number n!
    var acc = 1;
    while (n > 0) acc *= n--;
    return acc;
}
function facArray(params) {
    var f = [];
    for (var i=0; i<params.length; i++)
        f[i] = factorial(params[i]);
    return f;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could make use of this `fact` function taken from Felix Kling's answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4438131/factorial-of-a-number) and use `Array.map` and then `Array.join`

```
function fact(x) {
   if(x == 0) return 1;
   return x * fact(x-1);
}
function factorial(arr){
   var result = arr.map(fact);
   return result.join(",");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```
var array = [5,4,3,2,1];

document.write("<br>Facorial: " + factorial(array).join(','));

function factorial(params){
        var op = [];
        for (i = params.length - 1; i >= 0 ; i--){
            var f = 1;
            for (j = 0; j < i; j++){
                f = f * params[j];
            }
             op.push(f);
        }
       return op;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

That's all in a `while` :D

```
var array = [5,4,3,2,1];
var len = array.length-1;
while(len--) {
    array[len] *= array[len+1];
}

array;// [120, 24, 6, 2, 1]
```

Just multiply one by one from last to first.