# Finding the factorial using a loop in javascript

Tags: javascript, factorial

I need to use a loop to find the factorial of a given number. Obviously what I have written below will not work because when `i = inputNumber` the equation will equal 0.

How can I stop i reaching inputNumber?

```
var inputNumber = prompt('Please enter an integer');
var total = 1;

for (i = 0; i <= inputNumber; i++){
    total = total * (inputNumber - i);
}

console.log(inputNumber + '! = ' + total);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [factorial of a number](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4438131/factorial-of-a-number)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Fast factorial function in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3959211/fast-factorial-function-in-javascript)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here is an error `i <= inputNumber`

should be `i < inputNumber`

```js
var inputNumber = prompt('Please enter an integer');
var total = 1;

for (i = 0; i < inputNumber; i++){
    total = total * (inputNumber - i);
}

console.log(inputNumber + '! = ' + total);
```

Comment: or we can start the for loop from 1 for(i =1; i<=inputnumber; i++) and total = total * i;

Answer (score 2):

you can keep this:
    **i <= inputNumber**

and just do this change:
    **total = total * i;**

then the code snippet would look like this:

```
var inputNumber = prompt('Please enter an integer');
var total = 1;

for (i = 1; i <= inputNumber; ++i){
total = total * i;
}

console.log(inputNumber + '! = ' + total);
```

Comment: for(var i=1;  i< = inputnumber;  i++) too works isn't?

Answer (score 1):

```
var inputNumber = prompt('Please enter an integer');
var total = 1;

for (i = 0; i < inputNumber; i++){
    total = total * (inputNumber - i);
}

alert(inputNumber + '! = ' + total);
```

Comment: You should explain what changes you've made. It's not very helpful to just dump corrected code without explaining it.

Comment: Added explanation here:
Should replace the "i<=inputNumber" condition with "i<inputNumber"

Answer (score 1):

You could use the input value and a [`while` statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/while) with a prefix [decrement operator `--`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Decrement_(--)).

```js
var inputNumber = +prompt('Please enter an integer'),
    value = inputNumber,
    total = inputNumber;

while (--value) {                           // use value for decrement and checking
    total *= value;                         // multiply with value and assign to value
}

console.log(inputNumber + '! = ' + total);
```

Answer (score 1):

Using total *= i; will set up all of your factorial math without the need of extra code. Also, for proper factorial, you'd want to count down from your input number instead of increasing. This would work nicely:

```
var inputNum = prompt("please enter and integer");
var total = 1;
for(i = inputNum; i > 1; i--){
 total *= i;
}
console.log(total);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function factorialize(num) {
  
  var result = num;
  if(num ===0 || num===1){
    
    return 1;
  }
  
  while(num > 1){
    num--;
    result =num*result;
  }
  return result;
}

factorialize(5);
```

Comment: Perhaps explain your solution for readers to understand. Thanks.