# How to make a function that computes the factorial for numbers with decimals?

Tags: javascript, math, factorial, gamma-function

How can I make a function that calculates the factorial (or the [gamma function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function)) of decimal numbers in JavaScript? For example, how could I calculate `2.33!`?

Comment: What have you tried? At least there's a possible duplicated: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3959211/fast-factorial-function-in-javascript

Comment: function fact(n) {
  var x = 1
  
  for (var i = 2; i <= n; i++) {
   x = x * i
  }
  
  return x} But this can't compute factorials with decimals and i don't know how i can make a gamma function for it

Comment: I found that before and an answer but it's doesn't really goes exacly correct

Comment: You are right @Mich, voting up.

Comment: the array with constants doesn't seem to be correct

Comment: It's not trivial, so what is your background (did you read and understand http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function)? What do you need this for in javascript?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I might have found an existing solution...
It's an implementation of Lanczos method, I found it at the swedish wikipedia (http://sv.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gammafunktionen). It was written in python and says to be correct up to 15 decimals. I ported it to js, cross checked some random values against (http://www.efunda.com/math/gamma/findgamma.cfm).

http://jsfiddle.net/Fzy9C/

```
var g = 7;
var C = [0.99999999999980993, 676.5203681218851, -1259.1392167224028,771.32342877765313, -176.61502916214059, 12.507343278686905, -0.13857109526572012, 9.9843695780195716e-6, 1.5056327351493116e-7];

function gamma(z) {

    if (z < 0.5) return Math.PI / (Math.sin(Math.PI * z) * gamma(1 - z));
    else {
        z -= 1;

        var x = C[0];
        for (var i = 1; i < g + 2; i++)
        x += C[i] / (z + i);

        var t = z + g + 0.5;
        return Math.sqrt(2 * Math.PI) * Math.pow(t, (z + 0.5)) * Math.exp(-t) * x;
    }
}
```

(and ofcourse it does not support imaginary numbers, since js does not)

Answer (score 7):

As an alternative to the other answers here, here's a much simpler approximation for the gamma function, proposed in 2007 by Gergő Nemes. (See the wikipedia page on [Stirling's approximation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation#Versions_suitable_for_calculators)).

[image]

This can be implemented directly in JavaScript in a single line:

```
function gamma(z) {
  return Math.sqrt(2 * Math.PI / z) * Math.pow((1 / Math.E) * (z + 1 / (12 * z - 1 / (10 * z))), z);
}
```

You can [see this in action on jsFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/ebshB/1/)

This is accurate to 8 digits for z > 8, but **it is still accurate to a handful of digits for smaller z**. It is not quite as accurate as Lanczos approximation, but it is simpler and also [slightly faster](http://jsperf.com/gamma-function-implementations).

Note that the gamma function and the factorial function are slightly different. The factorial function can be defined in terms of the gamma function thus:

```
function factorial(n) {
  return gamma(n + 1);
}
```

Comment: Is there something incorrect here? I'd like to know why this was downvoted.

Comment: @PeterOhlson I'm not sure, but I get 3.11... instead of 1.27... when i do factorial(2.44) in jsfiddle. And i don't get other number to return a good value either... sorry about the downvote, i voted up but ran into this problem so ill vote up again if i see it functional. It't looks like a good solution.

Comment: @apelsinapa [3.11 is the correct answer](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=2.44%21). 1.27 is factorial(1.44), not factorial(2.44).

Comment: @PeterOhlson not accordning to: http://www.danielsoper.com/statcalc3/calc.aspx?id=30 and http://www.efunda.com/math/gamma/findgamma.cfm and http://www.miniwebtool.com/gamma-function-calculator/?number=2.44 ?

Comment: @apelsinapa That's because that's the *gamma* function, and the jsFiddle is the *factorial* function. They are slightly different. On the jsFiddle page you'll see the gamma function definition inside of the factorial function. If you like, [here's the gamma function by itself](http://jsfiddle.net/5EGXG/1/)

Comment: @PeterOhlson Haha, sorry I think it might be this beer =) By the way, its an far more elegant solution

Answer (score 4):

This is not a trivial problem. There is not a simple closed-form formula for the [gamma function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function). That said, there are some numerical approximations that should suit your needs.

The following answer will be using a technique called [Lanczos approximation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lanczos_approximation). The formula is as follows:

[image]

where g is an arbitrarily chosen constant that controls how accurate the approximation will be. For larger g, the approximation will be more accurate. A<sub>g</sub>(z) is defined thus:

[image]

The hardest part is finding A<sub>g</sub>(z), since [p<sub>n</sub> is also defined with a complicated formula dependent on g](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lanczos_approximation#Coefficients).

I can't take too much credit for the following code, since I am just writing a port of the Python program on the wikipedia page.

```
function gamma(n) {  // accurate to about 15 decimal places
  //some magic constants 
  var g = 7, // g represents the precision desired, p is the values of p[i] to plug into Lanczos' formula
      p = [0.99999999999980993, 676.5203681218851, -1259.1392167224028, 771.32342877765313, -176.61502916214059, 12.507343278686905, -0.13857109526572012, 9.9843695780195716e-6, 1.5056327351493116e-7];
  if(n < 0.5) {
    return Math.PI / Math.sin(n * Math.PI) / gamma(1 - n);
  }
  else {
    n--;
    var x = p[0];
    for(var i = 1; i < g + 2; i++) {
      x += p[i] / (n + i);
    }
    var t = n + g + 0.5;
    return Math.sqrt(2 * Math.PI) * Math.pow(t, (n + 0.5)) * Math.exp(-t) * x;
  }
}
```

and of course, by definition of the gamma function:

```
function factorial(n) {
  return gamma(n + 1);
}
```

You can [see this in action on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/twtY8/).

Answer (score 2):

Just to complete @apelsinapa answer to correct the calculation for an integer (we didn't get an integer solution when inputing an integer number).

@apelsinapa's great solution:

```
var g = 7;
var C = [0.99999999999980993, 676.5203681218851, -1259.1392167224028,771.32342877765313, -176.61502916214059, 12.507343278686905, -0.13857109526572012, 9.9843695780195716e-6, 1.5056327351493116e-7];

function gamma(z) {
    if (z < 0.5) return Math.PI / (Math.sin(Math.PI * z) * gamma(1 - z));
    else {
        z -= 1;

        var x = C[0];
        for (var i = 1; i < g + 2; i++)
        x += C[i] / (z + i);

        var t = z + g + 0.5;
        return Math.sqrt(2 * Math.PI) * Math.pow(t, (z + 0.5)) * Math.exp(-t) * x;
    }
}
```

And to get a correct answer for integer:

```
 function factorialOfNumber(number) {
    if (number % 1 != 0 || number<0){
        return gamma(number + 1);
    }
    else {
        if(number == 0) {
           return 1;
        }
        for(var i = number; --i; ) {
           number *= i;
        }
        return number;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a version I wrote a few years ago ... a bit messy but tested :)

```
var
    M_GAMMA = [76.18009172947146, -86.50532032941677, 24.01409824083091, -1.231739572450155, 0.1208650973866179e-2, -0.5395239384953e-5],
    M_GAMMAS = 6;

function gammaFn(x) // Modified to JavaScript from "Numerical Recipies in C" by P. Mainwaring
{
    var i = 0, n = ++x, tmp = x + 5.5, ser = 1.000000000190015;
    for (tmp -= (x + 0.5) * Math.log(tmp); i < M_GAMMAS; ++i) ser += M_GAMMA [i] / ++n;
    return Math.log(2.5066282746310005 * ser / x) - tmp;
}

function fact(x) { return x > 1 ? Math.exp(gammaFn(x)) : 1 }

function combin(n, k) { return (Math.exp(gammaFn(n) - gammaFn(n - k) - gammaFn(k)) + 0.5) | 0 } // Ms Excel COMBIN() n! / k!(n - k)!

n = 49; k = 6; alert(fact(n) + ' ' + fact(k) + ' ' + combin(n, k)); // Lottery odds! (13,983,816)
```

The gamma and gammaLn functions are then:

```
function gammaLn(x) { return gammaFn(--x) }

function gamma(x) { return Math.exp(gammaLn(x)) }
```

:-)

Answer (score 0):

If you're just looking for the function to compute factorials of real numbers then you only need this bit of code from Lanczos approximation:

```
function = factorial(z) {

  var g = 7;
  var C = [0.99999999999980993, 676.5203681218851, -1259.1392167224028, 771.32342877765313, -176.61502916214059, 12.507343278686905, -0.13857109526572012, 9.9843695780195716e-6, 1.5056327351493116e-7];
  var x = C[0];

  for (var i = 1; i < g + 2; i++)
  x += C[i] / (z + i);

  var t = z + g + 0.5;
  return Math.sqrt(2 * Math.PI) * Math.pow(t, (z + 0.5)) * Math.exp(-t) * x;
}
```

Works great for negative numbers in addition to decimals.