# Factorial of an integer

Tags: javascript

I have a question about an exercise (in JavaScript) regarding the factorial of an integer.
I have two conditions that I can't resolve:
The factorial of a negative number does not exist. How can I show this?
Enter decimal numbers using decimal point: 1.54. I think the decimals can be factorial too. But how?

```js
function fact(){
  
  var i;
  var number; 
  var f;

  f = 1;
  number = document.getElementById("number").value;

  for(i = 1; i <= number; i++)  {
    f = f * i;
  }
  i = i - 1;  

     
  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "The factorial of the number " + i + " is: " + f ;
}
```

```html
Enter a number: <input id = "number">
<button onclick = "fact()"> Factorial </button>
<p id = "result"></p>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The factorial of a negative number does not exist. How can I show this?

A simple `if` statement should allow you to check the value of `number`. If that value is below zero (meaning it's a negative number) then show a different message on the page:

```
if (number < 0) {
  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML =
    "Invalid input. A positive number is required";
}
```

---

> Enter decimal numbers using decimal point: `1.54`. I think the decimals can be factorial too. But how?

Wikipedia defines factorial as follows:

> In mathematics, the factorial of a non-negative *integer* n, denoted by n!, is the product of all positive integers less than or equal to n.

Which means that a value of `1.54` is not valid, since it is not an integer.

What to do about that is up to you. Some ideas:

- You could round the number first with `Math.round(number)`
- You could round the number down to the with `Math.floor(number)`
- You could present another error message when you detect the number is not an integer with something like `if (Math.floor(number) === number)`

Or as **@0stone0** points out in a comment to this answer, [fractional factorials can be a thing.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/454053/how-do-we-calculate-factorials-for-numbers-with-decimal-places) I'm not sure how to convert that math to javascript. But the point is that it's up to you how you want to handle these edge cases.

---

Lastly, it's worth talking about this line:

```
number = document.getElementById("number").value;
```

Here `number` is a string, not actually a number. This means it's the characters `"123"` instead of the number `123`. You probably want to use [`parseInt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) or [`parseFloat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat) on that value to make it a real number.

Javascript sometimes converts that string to a number for you when doing math operations, but it's not a good practice to rely on that as it can cause some bizarre and subtle bugs that are hard to understand.

Comment: Uhm, the Math Stack-exchange does not completely agree with that. [How do we calculate factorials for numbers with decimal places?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/454053/how-do-we-calculate-factorials-for-numbers-with-decimal-places) - [Gamma Function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function)

Comment: As reaction to Alex's edit mention my first comment. There are some decimal factorial numbers related questions asked here on Stack-overflow. One of those has a ported JavaScript solution: [How to make a function that computes the factorial for numbers with decimals?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15454183/how-to-make-a-function-that-computes-the-factorial-for-numbers-with-decimals)

Comment: Huh, interesting! Thanks for that @0stone0