# Am I wrong to feel this recursive function feels like a 'for loop?'

Tags: javascript, loops, recursion

Can someone explain how this recursive function produces 5 * 4 * 3 * 2 * 1 to get 120?

```
var factorial = function(n){
   if (n === 0)
       return 1;
   else
       return n * factorial(n - 1); 
};

factorial(5); // spits out 120
```

If we use 5 like like in the example, once we got to the else statement wouldn't

```
return n * factorial(n - 1);
```

translate to 'return 5 multiplied by the factorial function(5-1); 5 times...

Comment: Try stepping through it in a debugger.

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. Are you just asking how recursion works? You would be better off looking on wikipedia or a textbook, not this site.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Fast factorial function in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3959211/fast-factorial-function-in-javascript)

Comment: You'll realize the loop better if you try `factorial(-1)`?

Comment: I realized my answer never actually answered the question in your title, so I've updated it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Am I wrong to feel this recursive function feels like a 'for loop?'

No, recursion and loops have a lot in common. In particular, it's very important that they both have a termination condition. :-) In this case, that termination condition is `n === 0`.

The best way to understand this is to single-step through the code in a debugger. Your browser has one, so you could put that code in a page and load it and walk through it.

To get you started:

1. You call `factorial(5)`. Since `n` is not `=== 0`, `factorial` calls itself with `n - 1` (`4`)
2. Now we've recursed one level, and we're running `factorial(4)` (the call to `factorial(5)` still hasn't returned, it's waiting on us). Since `n` is not `=== 0`, we call `factorial(3)` and wait for *it* to return.
3. ...rinse, repeat until `factorial(0)` is called. Since `n === 0` is true (at that point, there are five calls to `factorial` outstanding and stacked up), `factorial(0)` returns `1`, and we can start unwinding the stacked up calls.
4. Now `factorial(1)` can finish by multiplying the result it got from `factorial(0)` by its copy of `n` (`1`) and returning that.
5. ...which lets `factorial(2)` finish and multiply that by `2`...
6. ...rinse repeat...

Or to put it another way showing the nesting (recursion):

```
factorial(5)
    return 5 * factorial(4)
        return 4 * factorial(3)
            return 3 * factorial(2)
                return 2 * factorial(1)
                    return 1 * factorial(0)
                        return 1
```

And because you can't get enough diagrams (or at least **I** can't):

```
factorial(5)    factorial(4)    factorial(3)    factorial(2)    factorial(1)    factorial(0)
    calls ---------->
                    calls ---------->
                                    calls ---------->
                                                    calls ---------->
                                                                    calls ----------->
                                                                                     n is 0, so
                                                                                     returns 1
                                                                                             |
                                                                    returns 1 * 1<-----------+
                                                                            = 1
                                                                              |
                                                    returns 2 * 1<------------+
                                                            = 2
                                                              |
                                    returns 3 * 2<------------+
                                            = 6
                                              |
                    returns 4 * 6<------------+
                            = 24
                              |
    returns 5 * 24<-----------+
            = 120

Result: 120
```

---

Side note: That function doesn't allow for negative numbers; it could probably use a guard at the beginning...

Comment: I like the nesting, it really drives the point home. Did you ever find your other answer?

Answer (score 3):

The `n` changes:

```
5 * factorial(5-1) = 5 * 4 * factorial(4-1) = 5 * 4 * 3 * factorial(3-1) = 5 * 4 * 3 * 2 * factorial(1-1) = 5 * 4 * 3 * 2 * 1
```

Also to make this function better you could stop it when `n` is equal to `1`, since the factorial of 1 is 1:

```
var factorial = function(n){
   if (n === 1 || n === 0)
       return 1;
   else
       return n * factorial(n - 1); 
};
```

Answer (score 2):

This function says: if you want to calculate factorial(5), well, that's really just

```
5 * factorial(4)
```

and if you want to calculate factorial(4), that's really just 4 * factorial(3)

```
5 * 4 * factorial(3)
```

and the thing about factorial(3) is that it's really just 3 * factorial(2)

```
5 * 4 * 3 * factorial(2)
```

and so on. But when you get down to factorial(0), the function finally stops (because of the `if n == 0` case) and returns 1, without any further recursion. So you get

```
5 * 4 * 3 * 2 * 1
```

`return n * factorial(n - 1)` translates to (on the first run), "return (5 * 4!)". It doesn't do anything 5 times.

Answer (score 1):

> If we use 5 like like in the example, once we got to the else statement wouldn't
>
> return n * factorial(n - 1);
>
> translate to 'return 5 multiplied by the factorial function(5-1); 5 times...

No, it would translate to 'return n multiplied by the factorial function (n-1)' (5 times, because n starts at 5, decrements and enters the else clause until it reaches 0).

1. When you first enter the function, n is equal to 5.
2. The if clause checks if n is equal to 0. It isn't, so it goes to:
3. The else clause. Which translates to 'return 5 multiplied by the factorial function (which you're in) (5 - 1).
4. When you enter the factorial function, n is now 4.

Repeat all of those steps until n is equal to 0. The if clause will then be true and the function will return 1.

So 1 is returned from factorial(0). Factorial(1) returns 1 * factorial(0), so 1 * 1 = 1.

Factorial(2) returns 2 * factorial(1), so 2 * 1 = 2.

Factorial(3) returns 3 * factorial(2), so 3 * 2 = 6.

Factorial(4) returns 4 * factorial(3), so 4 * 6 = 24.

Factorial(5) returns 5 * factorial(4), so 5 * 24 = 120.