# How to get Factorial of number in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, factorial

I'm learning Java Script and there is an exercise about getting the factorial of number user has entered but for some reason I always get answer is = 1

here is my code :

```
<SCRIPT>
function factorial(num){

    for (n=1; n<=num; n++){

    return fact*n;
    }
}

var myNum, fact;

myNum = parseFloat(window.prompt('Enter positive integer : ',''));
fact = 1;
document.write('the factorial of the number is = '+ factorial(myNum));



</SCRIPT>
```

Comment: The problem is your function `return`s too early.

Comment: First try searching to see if this has been asked before http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3959211/fast-factorial-function-in-javascript

Comment: Paste your code in your question. No snapshot, please.

Comment: Sorry for screenshot but when I tried to add actual code it got all wrong

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The pictured code (please include *actual* code in the future, not screenshots of code) returns `fact` immediately:

```
for ( n = 1; n <= num; n++ ) {
  return fact * n;
}
```

since `n` starts at `1`.

What you *want* is to include `fact` *in* the function, and multiply it as the loop goes along, *then* return:

```
function factorial(n) {
  var fact = 1;

  for ( n = 2; n <= num; n++ ) {
    fact = fact * n;
  }

  return fact;
}
```

Comment: I will mark this as Answer after 10min

Comment: Sorry for screenshot but when I tried to add actual code it got all wrong

Answer (score 0):

The reason this is returning 1 is because in your loop above, you return the value on the very first iteration, so n is never greater than 1.