# Factorize function javascript

Tags: javascript, factorial

I am having a little issue writing a function that factorizes numbers. The hard part is done. However I cannot seem to tell the function to return 1 when num is 0.

PS: which other ways would you write the same function in JavaScript?

```
var arrOfNum = [];

function factorialize(num) {

  for(i = 1; i <= num; i++){
    // push all numbers to array 
    arrOfNum.push(i);
  }

  // multiply each element of array
  var result = arrOfNum.reduce(function(a,b){
    return a * b;
  });

  console.log(result);
}
```

Comment: It looks like you're confusing "factorials" and "factorization".

Comment: check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3959211/fast-factorial-function-in-javascript also for a discussion on js factorial impl

Answer (score 3):

You already have a `for` loop, in which you can calculate the factorial at once, without array and reduce.

```
function factorial(num) {
  var result = 1;
  for(i = 2; i <= num; i++) {
      result *= i;
  }
  return result;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Roundup:

- Declaration of local variable `i` is missing

  ```
  var i;
  ```
- Declaration of other used variables are over the function distributed. A better way is to declare the variables at top of the function.
- [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) needs for this task an `initialValue` as the second parameter.

  > The first time the callback is called, `previousValue` and `currentValue` can be one of two values. If `initialValue` is provided in the call to reduce, then `previousValue` will be equal to `initialValue` and `currentValue` will be equal to the first value in the array. If no `initialValue` was provided, then `previousValue` will be equal to the first value in the array and `currentValue` will be equal to the second.

```js
function factorial(num) {
    var i,
        arrOfNum = [],
        result;

    for (i = 1; i <= num; i++) {
        // push all numbers to array 
        arrOfNum.push(i);
    }

    // multiply each element of array
    result = arrOfNum.reduce(function (a, b) {
        return a * b;
    }, 1);

    document.write(num+'! = '+result + '<br>');
}
factorial(0);
factorial(1);
factorial(2);
factorial(5);
factorial(8);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following method that uses the recursion:

```
function factorize(num){
    if(num === 0){
        return 1 ;
    }
    else {
        return num = num * factorize(num-1);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply return the value 1

```
 function factorialize(num) {
       if (num < 1) return 1; //this line is added

       for(i = 1; i <= num; i++){
         arrOfNum.push(i);
       }
       var result = arrOfNum.reduce(function(a,b){
          return a * b;
       });
        console.log(result);
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you give `reduce` an initial value of `1`, everything will work fine even without an explicit check:

```
var result = arrOfNum.reduce(function(a,b){
   return a * b;
 }, 1);
  ^^^         // PROVIDE EXPLICIT INITIAL VALUE TO REDUCE
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 function factorial(n) {
   return Array.apply(0, Array(n)).reduce(function(x, y, z) {
     return x + x * z; //1+(1*0), 1+(1*1),2+(2*2), 6+(6*3), 24+(24*4), ...
   }, 1);
 }
```

[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/dipali_vasani/q4030u8v/)

Comment: Are you sure about `x + x * z`?

Comment: @torazaburo yes, X: previousValue, Y: currentValue, Z: currentIndex so it will be like : 1+(1*0), 1+(1*1),2+(2*2), 6+(6*3), 24+(24*4), etc

Answer (score 0):

Here's a fairly streamlined function that returns an array of all factors of 'n'

You only need to look at candidates < sqrt(n)

For those of you who don't know the | 0; bit when getting sqrt(n) is a faster equivalent of Math.floor()

As factn is defined after some sanity checking the function will either return undefined or an array which is easy to check with something like if(factors = factorize(n) { success code } sorta structure

There are improvements that can be made to this but they're complex and were beyond the requirements when I wrote it - specifically I used this to calculate CSS sprite sizes from a large image by using factorize on the x + y dimensions of an image then creating a third array of shared factors (which gives you a list of all the possible square sprite sizes).

```
function factorize(n) {
    n = Number(n);
    if(n) {
        if(n > 1) {
            var sqrtn = Math.sqrt(n) | 0;
            var factn = [1, n];
            var ipos = 0;
            for(i = 2; i <= sqrtn; i++) {
                if((n % i) == 0) {
                    ipos++;
                    if((n / i) !== i) {
                        factn.splice(ipos, 0, i, n / i);
                    } else {
                        factn.splice(ipos, 0, i);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return factn;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't know why there are complicated answers. A very simple answer is:

```js
var i;

function factorialOf(num) {
    //Initially set factorial as number
    var factorial = num;
    
    //A for loop starting with 1 and running the times equal to num
    for (i = 1; i < num; i++) {
        //Set factorial to the number itself * i
        factorial = factorial * i;
    }
    //Return factorial
    return factorial;
}

console.log(factorialOf(5));
```