# Sum of Factorial numbers in javascript

Tags: javascript, numbers, factorial

I would like to sum the given factorials numbers in javascript

```
'1! + 2! + 3! + ... + n!'
```

Comment: I dont know how can write this programme.please help

Comment: I'd first learn some basics and look into functions and loops. Then I'd look into how to compute the factorial of a number. http://eloquentjavascript.net can help with functions and loops,  https://www.google.com with the rest.

Comment: While you are at it trying looking what dynamic programming is to speed up the computation.

Answer (score 0):

You may use factorial function :
Iterative function:

```
function sFact(num)
{
    var rval=1;
    for (var i = 2; i <= num; i++)
        rval = rval * i;
    return rval;
}
```

Recursive

```
function rFact(num)
{
    if (num === 0)
      { return 1; }
    else
      { return num * rFact( num - 1 ); }
}
```

I copied these function from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3959211/fast-factorial-function-in-javascript) link.
 Now what can you do is.

Suppose n value is 6.

```
  var n = 6;
    var sum = 0;
    for(var i=1;i<=n;i++)
    {
       sum = sum + rFact(i);//Here you can use one of factorial funciton. I am using recursive function
    }

document.print("The answer is "+ sum );
```

Comment: While it's certainly great that you want to help, I'd recommend to avoid low quality questions. Also, copying other answers is no-go.

Comment: Sure @Felix. I appreciate your recommendation.

Comment: @FelixKling i copied and mentioned as well.

Comment: I know... still not great. Just link to the answer if it is a part of yours. E.g. "See [link] for computing the factorial.". It only makes sense to quote if the other answer contains a lot of unrelated information or if you are linking to an external site.

Answer (score 0):

The naïve solution would be to actually calculate every factorial and add them together, which has a complexity of O(*n*²).  However, if you're clever, you can design an algorithm that solves the same problem with a complexity of O(*n*).  Take a look at the pattern of the following example that calculates the sum of the factorials of 1 through 4.

```
1!+2!+3!+4! =
1+1*2+1*2*3+1*2*3*4
```

Notice how you're reusing results from previous calculations multiple times?  This can be taken advantage of.  You can calculate the sum of all the factorials up to *n* with a program something like this.

```
function sumFactorials(n) {
    var sum = 0;
    var prod = 1;
    for(var i=1; i<=n; i++) {
        prod *= i;
        sum += prod;
    }
    return sum;
}
```