# Get factorial of all the numbers of array recursively

Tags: javascript, recursion

I am trying to get factorial of all the numbers of array(recurArray) using recursion and without loops.
I am getting Error "Maximum call stack size exceeded"
I think there is some issue with the for loop logic, would be helpful if someone can explain the cause of error and how to fix it

Thanks.

//code

```
function recur(){
 var n;
 var result;
 if(n == 1)
 return 1;
 var recurArray = [5,6,7,8,9];
 for (var i = 0;i<recurArray.length;i++){
    n = recurArray[i];
    result = n * recur(n-1);
    n=n-1;

 }
 console.log("val of n " + n  + "value of i " + i);
 return result;

}
recur();
```

Comment: Your `recur` function does not have any parameters?

Comment: Yes, you definitely should not use a `for` loop if you don't want to use loops

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Fast factorial function in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3959211/fast-factorial-function-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

Your `recur()` function should probably take `n` as an argument, otherwise `n` will never be `1` (`if(n == 1) return 1;`) and your function will keep calling itself until it crashes.

Try `function recur(n){` instead.

Comment: There's no `int` in javascript

Answer (score 0):

As you have array, you should use loop.

```js
function recur(x) {
   if(x==0) {
      return 1;
   }
   return x * recur(x-1);
}

function getFact() {
    var recurArray = [5,6,7,8,9];
    for (var i = 0;i<recurArray.length;i++){
      console.log(recur(recurArray[i]));
    }
}

getFact();
```

Comment: Thanks , Rishi, I am now able to get the factorials.

Answer (score 0):

In Each occurence you reset the factorial so it keep rolling for fact(5) you need to have a function that calculate the factorial and an other one for the loop over your array like this :

```
function recur(n){
   if(n == 1){
      return 1;
   } else {
      return n* recur(n-1);
   }
}


var recurArray = [5,6,7,8,9];
for (var i = 0;i<recurArray.length;i++){
    n = recurArray[i];
    result = recur(n);
    console.log("factorial of n " + n  + " is " + result);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
function factorial(number) {
var temp;

if(number <= 1) return 1;

temp = number * factorial(number - 1);
return temp;
}
```

In this case factorial(5); will return !5 . Recursive functions are not supposed to have loops inside(They can, but the execution time would be horrendous).
Also recursive functions call themselves with different parameters(otherwise you would overflow the browser stack). In your case you call recursive() an infinite amount of times and the loop always starts from 5 , infinitely. The passed parameter is what stops the recursion.