# Are there any build-in methods in JavaScript for finding the factorial of a number?

Tags: javascript, factorial

Are there any build-in methods for finding the factorial of a number which we can use in place of reusable functions like the example below:

```js
function factorial(x) {
  for (let i = x - 1; i >= 1; i--) {
    x= x * i; 
  }

  return x;
}

alert(factorial(16));
```

Comment: there are no built-in methods and trying to compute a large factorial eg (50) will overflow most probably you will need a bigint library for any serious factoial computation

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the fastest factorial function in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3959211/what-is-the-fastest-factorial-function-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1):

No, the [`Math` object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math) does provide no such method.

Answer (score 0):

There is no in-build factorial function. However, as a side note, you can simplify your function as following

```js
function factorial(x) {
  return (x > 1) ? x * factorial(x-1) : 1;
}

console.log(factorial(5));
```

Answer (score 0):

There are no built-in functions to do the factorial of a number in JavaScript, but you could make a .js file just for this purpose, and import it in each file you intend to use it for. 
Take a look at this question: [How do I include a JavaScript file in another JavaScript file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/950087/how-do-i-include-a-javascript-file-in-another-javascript-file) for importing files. I believe this is the closest you can get for what you want.

As Nikos already mentioned in a comment, you should beware overflowing for large factorial numbers, as the highest number you can get to is 2^53 - 1 for integers, or 2^32-1 for bitwise operations. Make your own BigInt library, or search for one: there exist many open-source ones out there.