# What is the Big O difference for iterative vs recursive?

Tags: javascript, big-o

What is the Big O difference for iterative vs recursive? And why are the run times so different.  I would assume O(n) as it has one loop for the iterative.

Here is a medium [article](https://medium.com/@lauren.kroner/understanding-big-o-notation-61ba6dbb2215) with a nice graph.

```
function factorial (n) {
  if( n === 0 || n === 1 ) {
    return 1;
  }
  let prev = 1;
  let ret;
  while(n >= 2) {
    ret = prev * n;
    prev = ret;
    n--;
  }
  return ret;
}

function factorialR (n) {
  if( n === 0 || n === 1 ) {
    return 1;
  } else {
    return n * factorialR(n - 1);
  }
}
```

The recursive version seems to take significantly longer.  See [SO Q/A here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3959211/what-is-the-fastest-factorial-function-in-javascript).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, those functions both have `O(n)` computational complexity, where n is the number passed to the initial function call.

The first function executes the (`O(1)` complexity) statements in the `while` loop for every value between a larger `n` and 2, for an overall complexity of `O(n)`.

The second function recursively calls itself `n` times, without any loops, for (again) an overall complexity of `O(n)`.

If you wanted to reduce the computational complexity for *multiple* calls of the functions, I'd create a lookup table to save the values calculated from previous calls, resulting in `m` calls of the function running in `O(n)` (where `n` is the highest number ever passed), rather than `m` calls running in `O(n * m)` (or `O(n^2)`) time.

If

> The recursive version seems to take significantly longer.

this is *not* due to computational complexity, but due to how the compiler works with the different approaches. Function calls generally have more of an overhead than a simple `while` loop (though, this sort of optimization is almost never something to worry about in real life - code readability and maintainability is more important most of the time).

Comment: Thanks, I kind of got that already.  The question was more .... why is the time so different for the same `n` ... 5ms compared to 150ms and how can this be captured in Big O or can it not be.

Comment: If you're referring to Gabriele Petrioli's answer, that part is pretty misleading - he's using `Date.now` (which is not very precise) *and* is only running a relatively small number of iterations (compared to a real performance test). It also looks to be inaccurate, I'm getting 3-5ms vs 10-15ms here: https://jsfiddle.net/s7ue6gtq/ in the latest version of Chrome. But 5ms vs 150ms is *possible*, even with the same computational complexity (given the overhead of a function call is).

Comment: Does JavaScript have tail call optimization?

Comment: @laptou It's *supposed* to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37224520/are-functions-in-javascript-tail-call-optimized but very few environments have implemented it yet, unfortunately

Comment: So you could say that it is O(n) for both except the constant is much greater for the recursive calls?

Comment: @jakobdennison Exactly. If you did 1e20 tests for both approaches, maybe each would take something *around* 1e17 ms to complete - if their Big O was different, eg if one was `O(n^2)`, that one might take something like 1e34 ms to complete instead. The huge difference is visible with huge inputs.