# Factorialise all numbers in array with .map

Tags: javascript, arrays, array.prototype.map

I have an array of numbers e.g. [2, 4, 5] and must get the factorials in a new array. E.g. [2, 24, 120]

I am using .map as you can see to perform the function on each integer in the array however, this does not work? I assume something is wrong with the recursive function?

Thanks.

```
function getFactorials(nums) {

if(nums > 1){
    factarr = nums.map(x => x * (nums - 1));
}

return factarr;
}
```

Comment: I'm not a math master, but factorial(4) should be 4*3*2*1, right? if so, your is not doing that.

Comment: no factorial 4! is 4x3x2x1 :)

Comment: sorry, meant that. Your code is not doing that, though ;)

Comment: `nums` is supposed to be an array or a number?

Comment: "*I assume something is wrong with the recursive function*" there is no recursive function here.

Comment: it seems to work for single integers in an array but not multiple... any help is appreciated!

Comment: You code is neither working for a single integer nor an array. Try first to make it work with a single integer and then extend it to an array

Comment: nums is an array like [6] or [1,2,3]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could take a function for the factorial and map the values.

The function has a recusive style with a check for the value. if the value is zero, then the function exits with one. Otherwise it returnd the product of the actual value and the result of the call of the function with decremented value.

The check uses an implict casting of a [falsy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy) to a boolean value for the [conditional (ternary) operator `?:`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator).

```js
const fact = n => n ? n * fact(n - 1) : 1;

var array = [2, 4, 5],
    result = array.map(fact);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: thank you! i will try this. did not think to separate them :)

Comment: this worked :) can you explain a little more on what is happening on the first line though? that would be appreciated

Comment: @Tony `fact` is a function whose signature accepts an argument (n). If (n) is truthy (hence, if it's not 0, in your particular scenario), it returns n multiplied by fact(n - 1), otherwise it returns 1. Basically, it returns n * fact(n-1) recursively until n is not truthy anymore.

Comment: @Nina_Scholz The ternary operator should have this condition `const fact = n => (n > 1) ? n * fact(n - 1) : 1;` or else It may throw `StackOverlow` for negative numbers :)

Comment: @VedantTerkar, [`factorial`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorial) is only defined for positive integer numbers.

Answer (score 1):

Just create a function that calculates the factorial of a given number then just use it as the callback for the `map` function.

As the main part is the way to calculate the factoriel, here's two manners to do that task

Factoriel function iterative way :

```js
const fact = n => {
  let f = 1,
  i = n;
  for(; i > 1; i--) f *= i;
  return f;
};

console.log(fact(4)); /** outpuut: 24 **/
```

Factoriel function recursive way :

```js
const fact = n => n > 1 ? n * fact(n - 1) : n;

console.log(fact(4)); /** outpuut: 24 **/
```

And the final code :

```js
const arr = [2, 4, 5],
  fact = n => n > 1 ? n * fact(n - 1) : n,
  factArr = arr.map(i => fact(i));

console.log(factArr); /** output: [2, 24, 120] **/
```

Comment: you're welcome, feel free to ask for explanations if needed.

Answer (score 0):

You are doing the recursion wrong, my approach would be to define the factorial calculator as a separate function:

```js
function getFactorials(nums) {
  function factorial(n){
    return n === 0 ? 1 : n * factorial(n - 1);
  }
  return nums.map(x => factorial(x));
}
console.log(getFactorials([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ,6]));
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to calculate each factorial in array, your current code is not doing that. Consider following example:

```
function factorial(num) {
    if (num === 0 || num === 1) {
    return 1;
  } else {
    return num * factorial(num - 1);
  }
}

const facts = [2, 4, 5];
const factsArr = facts.map(num => factorial(num));
```

In you code you was just multiplying each member of array by array itself.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing it recursively, I took the solution from [@Amin Jafari](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48838431/9758920) which uses `reduce()`. This function is **quicker** than the recursive solution.

First we generate an array. We do so by using `Array(n + 1)`. `n` is the factorial so e.g. for `6!` our `n` would be `6`. We get the indices with `keys()` but `Array()` by itself only returns a truly empty array and `keys()` only returns an iterator. So we spread it and put the result of that into a new array. Thus, we have e.g. `[0,1,2,3,4,5,6]` (for `n + 1` with `n = 6`). We exclude the 0 with `slice(1)`.

Afterwards we finally apply `reduce`. Reduce iterates over all elements, applies a function while keeping track of an accumulator. Our accumulator here is the current product. So what happens is that `1 * 2` gets calculated and the result saved in `a`, our accumulator. Then we multiply `a` with the next value, so `2 * 2*` and this happens until we went through our whole self generated array.

This function based on `reduce` we can then use to transform each value in our original array with `map()`.

```js
const factorial = n => [...Array(n+1).keys()].slice(1).reduce((a,c) => a * c),
      data = [2, 4, 5];

let res = data.map(v => factorial(v));

console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

I know that this post has a lot of answers already, but I might have something to add:

If you are planning to use the recursive function a lot to calculate factorials, let's say you need this in a browser game every .5 secs, you will notice that it is consuming *a lot* of resources, mainly your time .

My proposition is:

- calculate the factorials once
- store them in the app state
- look them up instead of calculating them

example code (based on Nina Scholz's anwer):

```
// create this earlier, put it in the application state
const state = {lookupFact: []}

const fact = n => n ? n * fact(n - 1) : 1;

// only calculate the factorials once
function lookupFact(par) {
  if (state.lookupFact.length == 0) {
    for (var i = 0; i <= 170; i++) {
      state.lookupFact[i] = fact(i)
    }
  }
  return state.lookupFact[par]
}

// use it like this later on
console.log(lookupFact(1), lookupFact(10), lookupFact(5))
```

As I said, you should use this only if you have to calculate factorials *all the time*.

Answer (score 0):

```
var arr = [2,3,4,5,6,7]

arr.map((value, ind) => {
  var facts = 1;
  for (value  ;value > 0 ;value--) {
    facts = facts *value;
  }
  console.log(facts);
})
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.