# My factorial program does not work (in javascript)

Tags: javascript, for-loop, factorial

```js
function factorial(num) {
  var factorialValue = 1;
  if (num === 0) {
    return factorialValue;
  } else {
    for (var i = num; i <= 1; i--) {
      factorialValue *= i;
    }
    return factorialValue;
  }
}

console.log(factorial(10));
console.log(factorial(5));
console.log(factorial(3));
console.log(factorial(0));
```

What's the problem in my code? It works only 1.

// thx for your codes!!!

Comment: You're looping ***while `i` is under 1***…?!

Comment: for loop is not correct.. needs to be `i > 0`

Comment: Did you mean `>= 1`?

Comment: Change `i<=1` to `i>=1`. Or simply `i>1`.

Comment: Thx for your comments everyone!! I got it:)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the fastest factorial function in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3959211/what-is-the-fastest-factorial-function-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1):

```js
function factorial(num) {
  var factorialValue = 1;
  for (var i = num; i > 1; i--) {
    factorialValue *= i;
  }
  return factorialValue;
}

console.log(factorial(10));
console.log(factorial(5));
console.log(factorial(3));
console.log(factorial(0));
```

But I think you can use memoization (or recursion) instead of for-loops.

```js
function factorial (n){
  if (n==0 || n==1)
    return 1;
  return factorial(n-1)*n;
} 

console.log(factorial(10));
```

Comment: You can also remove the __if__ condition, as `0<1` evaluates to false before the very first iter. However, it'll make it ~1% cryptic.

Answer (score 0):

**You can use a more simple code, using recursion. Enjoy!**

```js
function factorial(num) {
  if (num === 0) {
    return 1;
  } else {
    return num * factorial(num-1);
  }
}

console.log(factorial(10));
console.log(factorial(5));
console.log(factorial(3));
console.log(factorial(0));
```